# Is it possible to make mat-grid-tile selectable?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I want to make mat-grid-tile selectable just like radio button.

<mat-grid-list cols="3" rowHeight="1:1" [gutterSize]="'30px'" style="width:90%">

```
                    <mat-grid-tile *ngFor="let package of packageList" class="package-box">

                        <div style="display: flex; flex-direction:column; text-align: center;">
                            <div>
                                <h2>
                                    {{package.package_name}}
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <p>${{package.mrp_price}}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </mat-grid-tile>

                </mat-grid-list>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a state or Variable to keep Track True/False
and add a click method on the title then switch between true/false

then you can add a conditional class in your title
so if your state or variable is true the class is active, then you can just apply style to that class however you want